# A problem about a calculus equivalence of inflection point

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, graphing-functions

**The problem:**

Given $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function on the interval $(a,b)$, and $g: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying:
$$g(x) = \begin{cases}\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0} & \text{ if } x \in D \setminus\{x_0\} \\ \;\;\;\;\;f'(x_0) & \text{ if } x=x_0\end{cases}$$
, whereas $x_0 \in (a,b)$.

Decide whether the following propositions are equivalent:

$\text{i)} \; f'$ has a local extremum at $x_0$.

$\text{ii)} \; g$ has a local extremum at $x_0$.

$\;$

*Note:* The problem doesn't include whether $f$ is twice-differentiable at $x_0$ or on the interval $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider on the interval $(-1, 1)$ the function $f(x) = Ax^2 + x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x})$ (with $f(0)$ defined to be $0$ to fill in the hole).

For $A = 1$, $g$ has an extremum (namely $0$) at $x = 0$. But $f'$ does not.

The extremum of $g$ is weak, though: $g(x) = 0$ for values of $x$ arbitrarily near $0$.

But if you pick $A > 1$, then $g$ has a strict extremum.

BTW, this function is my go-to function for anything involving reasonable-sounding statements about derivatives. Hope it's of some service to you as well. (Spivak's  *Calculus* goes into some detail about this and related functions for the beginner, although you're probably well past that or you wouldn't be asking this question.)